# Lightning Experience embedded VisualForce page gets vertically truncated

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

My standard page layout has a Visualforce page embedded. When this embedded page is rendered in Classic it shows properly but when in Lightning Experience, it appears to be forced to a shorter height, no buttons at the bottom are showing and also there is no scrollbar. I am using 'lightningStyleSheets' attribute. In the embedded page settings,  show scrollbars is not checked, and I think that might be the reason why I do not see scrollbars? I do not see the entire content of the embedded page , and there are no scroll bars to scroll to see it. Any suggestions or ideas are welcome. Below are screenshots for classic and lightning. Any ideas?

[image: Lightning Experience]

[image]

Comment: I had the same thing happen. I think it has to do with the lightning CSS using far more white space. I just gave the visualforce page 25px extra height in the page layout and that fixed it. But that might not be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Kasper I did the same thing. I added 100px to the embedded page height and I see the scroll bar.